# Trying to show alt text for all images in easySlider carousel

Tags: jquery, html, append, image

I have the following html:

```
<div id="slider">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" filename="strangeweather_1"><img src="large/strangeweather_1.jpg" alt="Baby, You're Just Like Stereo Equipment - ink, watercolor, gouache on paper" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" filename="strangeweather_2"><img src="large/strangeweather_2.jpg" alt="I Don't Mind If You Sleep Through This Or It Wakes You - ink, gouache, watercolor on paper" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" filename="strangeweather_3"><img src="large/strangeweather_3.jpg" alt="It's Not Over Yet - ink, watercolor, gouache, graphite on paper" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="contentTitle"><!-- append alt text here -->
</div>
```

My jQuery looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var altText = $(this).find('#slider ul li img').attr('alt');
   $('div#contentTitle').append(altText);
```

});

That seems to work for the first img alt when the doc loads. Not sure how to display the alt text of each image as it is loaded through the carousel.

Does jquery effectively take a copy of the alt and store it for manipulation? I was thinking about using .offset() to show the alt at an absolute position. I don't know how to display the alt each time the current image is loaded.

Hope this makes sense.

All the code is here: http://dev.jessicaharby.com/work/

Answer (score 0):

you can try [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#slider ul li img').each(function() {
         $('div#contentTitle').append($(this).attr('alt'));
   }); 
})
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7zs5W/3/)

Comment: That is kind of working except that it is appending the alt text of every image simultaneously, I don't know how to simply append the single image that the client is looking at. But not sure if the carousel can work that way.

Comment: Do you think the alt text of each image can be laid on top of the image, wherever it is on the page? I can see it when I disable images in Firebug.

Comment: @lharby alt _ernative_ is used when an image is not loaded, you can create an element base on that and position it relative to the image using javascript. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: The images are stored in a carousel and fade in from right to left. If the alt text could stay with the coordinates of the image as it slides, that would be ideal. Goes back to my question about jQuery copying the object and storing it rather than manipulating the dom element. Check this: http://db.tt/SiF2aVEV Firebug with images disabled, if you scroll the images the alt text moves with the image. All code here: http://dev.jessicaharby.com/

Comment: @lharby okay, why don't you use a carousel plugin which supports caption?

Comment: Yeah maybe. I'll look into it.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

**Update**: Fixed typos

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     var altText = "";
     $('#slider ul li img').each(function(a, b){
        altText += $(b).attr('alt') + "<br/>";
     });

   $('#contentTitle').append(altText); //Remove the div from the slecttor, since you are using ID selector this version is faster.
});
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vsDze/

Comment: I cannot see anything working in the jsfiddle. If you go here: http://dev.jessicaharby.com/ it's sort of working, but loading the alt of every image into the div.